# Very low GPU usage while rendering

Tags: rendering, gpu

My GPU usage is at around 5 to 9 percent.

[image: low GPU usage]
[image]

I would like to know if it is normal? And why?

Comment: because the scene is not complex enough to use more of GPU

Comment: The Task Manager doesn't show CUDA usage by default. You will have to switch to the *Performance* tab, select the GPU then change one of the panels to *CUDA* by clicking on the name.

Comment: Okay, thank you both

Answer (score 1):

If you have a NVIDIA GPU and would like to see the real GPU usage, you have to use the CUDA tab in Windows Taskmanager. If you are on Windows...

Comment: Okay, but Optix is better?

Comment: @Hunam this site is not a forum, but a question and answers site. To keep things organized you can ask new questions as a  new post, not as comments. Please take a minute to read the [tour] to understand how to make better use of this pages.